# Why there isn't lexicographically smallest solution to a bounded linear program?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, computational-geometry

I am learning computational geometry when I run into this confusion. "A bounded 2D linear program may not have a lexicographically smallest solution", as the book says. I wonder why? I think we can always choose an "optimal vertex" from the feasible region based on either x-coordinates or y-coordinates.

Can anyone provide an example where a 2D LP that is bounded, but no lexicographically smallest solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the linear programming problem

minimize $y$ subject to $y \ge 0$, $y \le 1$, $x \le 0$

where there are optimal solutions $(x, 0)$ for $-\infty < x \le 0$.  The point is that
although the **problem** is bounded, the **feasible region** is not.

Comment: Great! Thanks! It seems that I had a very limited understanding of a bounded LP problem.

Comment: @Y.Luo you should click the blue V to accept this answer.